# Separating data adapter and gridview into a class file

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataadapter

I am trying to separate my code out into class files.  However the issue I am having is how do I access `dataGridviewLogging` that is contained within `Form1` from the class file?

```
public void getLogging(String sql)
{
    SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, mycon);       
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "LOG_MESSAGE");
        dataGridViewLogging.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridViewLogging.DataMember = "LOG_MESSAGE";
    }
    catch (Exception f)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show("FAILURE:" + f.ToString());
        return;
    }
}
```

I've been trying to think of a way I could do this? Ideas?

Comment: You should not do it. Your class should hold entities and abstract data types that are not related to the page layout.

Answer (score 0):

Since your method is named `getLogging` you want to return data which can be used as a DataSource. So instead of setting the datasource here, you should set it at where you can access the databound control.

For example (in Form1):

```
dataGridViewLogging.DataSource = getLogging(
          DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-6)
        , DateTime.Today);  // don't pass the sql directly, use parameters instead
```

and in your class:

```
public DataSet getLogging(DateTime logFrom, DateTime logTo)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    const string sql = "SELECT Columns FROM dbo.Table WHERE LoggedAt BETWEEN @LoggedFrom AND @LoggedTo ... ODRER BY ...";
    using (var mycon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, mycon))
    {
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoggedFrom", logFrom);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoggedTo", logFrom);
        try
        {
            da.Fill(ds);
        } catch (Exception f)
        {
            // log here
            throw;
        }
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that class return a dataset.  Where is the return statement?

Comment: @user1158745: Of course, edited my answer accordingly. By the way, use `SqlParameters` if you want to filter with custom parameters which values you could add as argument to this method. That's why i've made the sql string a constant. Parameters will also prevent sql-injection.

Comment: @user1158745: Edited my answer to show how you would use parameters.

Comment: Sorry I am not follwing:  In the class we are returning the data set.  now how to I utilize this in my form?

Comment: Ok i think this is not what i wanted.   I simply wanted to seperate my code but the dataset doesn't really allow you to do that.

Comment: @user1158745: I don't understand, in my sample code above it is separated. Your form uses a DAL class to get the data. Then it uses that data as datasource for a datagrid (even with the possibility to filter by date). Of course that is not working since i don'
t know your data model, it's just an example(but it compiles).

Comment: This part doens't work     using (var dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, getConnection))  it's expecting a sql conneciton.  I already have it devided

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18579/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-user1158745)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like tier architecture ... presentation, business logic and DataAccess.

Create a method or Function that take String as command Text, specify your command Type (SP or inline command)

Use it to get DataSet or DataTable as Returning Object.

```
Public DataTable GetDataTableFromDB(String CommandText,
                                    SqlCommandType type,
                                    SqlParameter [] param)
{
    DataTable temp=somthing;
    /* your logic */
    return DataTable;
}
```

Use this as class file and Get your dataset at your form1 class or form1.cs (if you are c# bee)

Have a great time, after all code for FUN!